Flutter - Display multiple items per line in a list
In my Flutter application I need to display a list with one or two item cards per line accordingly to the property singleLine. If it's true, the item must be displayed in the whole line, if it's false then I need to check the next item. If both have singleLine as false, then I must display both in the same line, otherwise both will be displayed in separate lines using full width. For example, consider the following list:
final cards = [
  {"title": "Item 1", "singleLine": true},
  {"title": "Item 2", "singleLine": false},
  {"title": "Item 3", "singleLine": false},
  {"title": "Item 4", "singleLine": true},
  {"title": "Item 5", "singleLine": true},
  {"title": "Item 6", "singleLine": false},
  {"title": "Item 7", "singleLine": true},
  {"title": "Item 8", "singleLine": false},
  {"title": "Item 9", "singleLine": false},
];

In this case I want to display this in the screen:
Item 1
Item 2   Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6
Item 7
Item 8   Item 9

How can I do this?

You could probably do this using some kind of grouping on the list then filtering through the groups.

A faster way to implement this would be to just create a 2 dimensional Widget List using a either Text widgets or Row widgets, then setting that as the "children" property of a Column widget as follows:
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const List<Map<String, dynamic>> cards = [
    {"title": "Item 1", "singleLine": true},
    {"title": "Item 2", "singleLine": false},
    {"title": "Item 3", "singleLine": false},
    {"title": "Item 4", "singleLine": true},
    {"title": "Item 5", "singleLine": true},
    {"title": "Item 6", "singleLine": false},
    {"title": "Item 7", "singleLine": true},
    {"title": "Item 8", "singleLine": false},
    {"title": "Item 9", "singleLine": false},
  ];

  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> arrangedCards = [];
    List<Card> cardCache = [];
    for (Map<String, dynamic> card in cards) {
      if (card["singleLine"] == true) {
        if (cardCache.isNotEmpty) {
          arrangedCards.add(Row(
            children: cardCache.toList(),
          ));
          cardCache.clear();
        }
        arrangedCards.add(Card(
          child: Text(card["title"]),
        ));
      } else {
        cardCache.add(Card(
          child: Text(card["title"]),
        ));
      }
    }
    if (cardCache.isNotEmpty) {
      arrangedCards.add(Row(
        children: cardCache,
      ));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: arrangedCards,
      ),
    );
  }
}

It just traverses the list one time and creates the page using the simplest and fastest built widgets.

I think there's no specific widget that does this, but it can be fulfilled by using some logic.
Look at the following ListView's builder:
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const List<Map<String, dynamic>> cards = [
    {"title": "Item 1", "singleLine": true},
    {"title": "Item 2", "singleLine": false},
    {"title": "Item 3", "singleLine": false},
    {"title": "Item 4", "singleLine": true},
    {"title": "Item 5", "singleLine": true},
    {"title": "Item 6", "singleLine": false},
    {"title": "Item 7", "singleLine": true},
    {"title": "Item 8", "singleLine": false},
    {"title": "Item 9", "singleLine": false},
  ];

  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text('One or two in a line'),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: cards.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if (index < cards.length - 1) {
                      if (cards[index]['singleLine'])
                        return Text(cards[index]['title']);
                      else {
                        if (!cards[index + 1]['singleLine']) {
                          return Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(cards[index]['title']),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 25,
                              ),
                              Text(cards[index + 1]['title']),
                            ],
                          );
                        } else {
                          return Text(cards[index + 1]['title']);
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}

and here's the result:

Hope it helps you.
